# Python semantic linting

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-ale

I'm currently using `ALE` (recently upgraded to this from `syntastic`) and `YCM` for code completion, highlighting syntax errors on-the-fly (rather than just at save time, like with `syntastic`), and it's working great. However, I'd like to integrate more advanced `lint`ing beyond syntax errors and PEP8 compliance. For example, I'd like obvious coding mistakes like so to be hightlighted/announced:

```
# Beginning of .py file.
a = b # Should error-out, warning that `b` has not yet been defined.
a = 1
```

Are there any advanced linters for Python (and, optionally, C, C++, and go) that can be used to point out simple/obvious semantic errors either on-the-fly (i.e. via `ALE`) or whenever the file is saved (like with `syntastic`)?

I'm currently using `vim` from `git` on `master` on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Thank you.

Comment: Im sorry, but i fail to see how a request for advanced static analyzers is (a) relevant to a vi/vim sight and (b) couldnt be solved by research

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about vi/vim, but rather static analysis tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was easier than expected. It just boils down to installing the `pip` and `apt` packages for `pylint` and `flake8`, i.e.:

```
sudo apt install pylint
sudo apt install flake8
pip install pylint
pip install flake8
```

This of course needs to use `pip-python3` instead of `pip` if you've configured `YCM` with Python3. From there, I just install the [YCM](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) and [`w0rp/ale`](https://github.com/w0rp/ale) packages via [`vundle`](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim).

The only caveat is that PEP8 (via `flake8`) errors will be rendered immediately, but other syntax errors detected by `pylint` will only be updated/re-rendered when the buffer is saved. However, [there's an open issue on this topic,](https://github.com/w0rp/ale/issues/590) which is on the backlog to be resolved, [as the underlying issue in `pylint` is now fixed,](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1187) and we're now just [waiting on an update to `ale`](https://github.com/w0rp/ale/issues/2522) to support a plugin supplying buffers both via `stdin` and via file buffers.